# How to use callback funciton for twitter, pinterest, and tumblr to count the share?

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter, tumblr, pinterest

I have been struck in the callback function for the twitter, tumblr and pinterest.

I am sucessed in share the things with these social site as they have their own sharing function. but unable to count the share in my system.

Can anybody help me for this problem?

Comment: Fancy sharing what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer this link  [How to get the social share count for facebook, twitter, linkedin and pinterest](http://dimboiu.com/how-to-get-the-social-share-count-for-facebook-twitter-and-linkedin/)

This is a sample code for twitter

```
function getTwitterCount($url){

$twittercount = json_decode( file_get_contents(http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url='.$url ) );

return $twittercount->count;}
```